# hodoku.jar on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, java

I have used `hodoku.jar` successfully on Ubuntu 16.04, my prior version.

Now I cannot get it to run. I have the two OpenJDF Java Runtime installed (8 & 11). I have the `.jar` set to execute, but it doesn't. I have also tried the Hodoku user manual suggested

```
java -Xmx512m -jar hodoku.jar
```

command. And also tried it with the option `-Xmx1024m`.

I really like this game and would like to get it running again.
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Try to run it with Java 8. You can set the current Java version with `update-alternatives --config java`. Then execute `java -jar executable.jar`. Maybe this does help.

Comment: That worked, except I needed to "sudo" before the command. Appreciate your help.